# How can I save graphics.Path variable in SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I import this package:

```
import android.graphics.Path;
```

to create Path variable, how can I save this Path variable in SharedPreferences?

Comment: Save the data that you used to create the `Path`, so you can re-create the `Path` again later.

Comment: its good idea but i cant do it becuse i have a lot of changes and i need just the last version of the Path variable, do you have more idea?

Comment: Have you got any solution? I have stuck here also :(

Answer (score -2):

you can use GSON library to convert it to string and save it in the SharedPreferences like this

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String strPath = gson.toJson(pathVariable);
```

and to convert the string to path object again you can do this

```
Path path = gson.fromJson(strPath, Path.class);
```

Comment: this is only returning {"isSimplePath":false}